# Is there a way to apply a Query Calculation Column in Cognos that determines 'real' (Built) from 'interim' (Not Built) regarding VINs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, equation, cognos, custom-errors

After downloading the intended report out of Cognos, in Excel I use the following formula as a column to inform if the VIN is built or unbuilt.

The formula I use in excel: [image: Additional formula added in excel]

When I inputted this as a Query Calculation Column in Cognos, I am receiving QE-DEF-0260 Parsing error before or near position, QE-DEF-0261 qfwp - parsing text, qe-def-0459 CCLException errors.

How do I write this formula/equation using Cognos 'language'?

Comment: Right.  You can't just paste an Excel formula into ...well... anything else.  Maybe I'm getting hung up on something less important.  Please define VIN (maybe it's not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number) and provide sample data.  `MID(<cellref>,14,15)` doesn't make sense for a 17-character value.

Comment: To determine whether a substring is numeric may require using vendor specific functions in Cognos.  Please tag this question with the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can use the `ISNUMERIC` function.

```
if (isnumeric(substring ([VIN], 14, 15)) = 1)
then ('Real VIN')
else ('Interim')
```

or

```
case
    when isnumeric(substring ([VIN], 14, 15)) = 1
        then 'Real VIN'
    else 'Interim'
end
```

Using Oracle, MySQL, etc. would require that you use a different function.

If your data source is an uploaded Excel file or similar, you may need to create more complicated logic.